# Alexa Skill Kit - To save user input

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Is there a way to save the user input to a variable in ALexa Skill kit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating an intent using Skill Builder, you can specify the Slot using curly brackets.

[image]

You can also define a Slot Type. You can define your own types or choose from built-in types.

[image]

Check the complete list here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html

From your Alexa skill (lambda function) you capture that a user is saying. You can get it from:

```
this.event.request.intent.slots.<SlotName>.value
```

Then you do with the value what do you want.

**Update:**

Interaction schema would be:

```
  {
    "name": "MyColorIsIntent",
    "samples": [
      "my favorite color is {Color}"
    ],
    "slots": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "type": "LIST_OF_COLORS"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the answer. However i was asking in the interaction model without launching the Skill builder. Any idea on it?

Comment: I've added an example of interaction model

Answer (score 1):

Yeah You can do that. You can store any information given by user using slots. You can use built in slots or you can also define your custom slots.

You can use built in slots if you want to get or store numbers or date or name of person etc.
Refer this link for list of Built In slots : https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html

If you want to store whole statement given by user then you can use AMAZON.SearchQuery:

As you think about what users are likely to ask, consider using a built-in or custom slot type to capture user input that is more predictable, and the AMAZON.SearchQuery slot type to capture less-predictable input that makes up the search query.

Make sure that your skill uses no more than one AMAZON.SearchQuery slot per intent. The Amazon.SearchQuery slot type cannot be combined with another intent slot in sample utterances.